# Relative path to database file in Java

Tags: java

I have to access a database file in my Java project but I can't get the path right.

The full path is `C:\Hogwarts\db\hogdb.fdb`.

I tried to use this code line to find the the current relative path:

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString(); 
System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);
```

and it says the current relative path is: `C:\Hogwarts`.

Right now my code looks like this :

```
minDataBas = new InfDB("db\\HOGDB.FDB");
new HuvudFonster(minDataBas).setVisible(true);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe i should add that the program has to work when i send it to someone else, that's why i don't want to use the C:\Hogwarts\db\hogdb.fdb path.

Comment: I put that in my answer (which was somewhat unclear). You would just need to append the "db\\HOGDB.FDB" to the current working directory. This would only work if the database file is similarly relative to the CWD on each computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [InfDB.java](https://github.com/DegJ/InfDB/blob/master/src/oru/inf/InfDB.java) file:

> @param path Path to the Firebird DB, for example C:/DB.FDB or for Mac /User/DB.FDB

Providing the absolute path, as opposed to relying on the method inferring you are using a relative path, should resolve the issue. Hence, use:

`minDataBas = new InfDB("C:\\Hogwarts\\db\\HOGDB.FDB");`

or if you know that the database file will be similarly relative to the current working directory for wherever it has launched, you could use the previously found working directory path and append the remaining location as such

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
minDataBas = new InfDB(s + "\\db\\HOGDB.FDB");
```

If you cannot be sure where the file will there are a variety of techniques you could use to have the user define where the file is. Setting a path variable, configuration files or simply taking user input.

Answer (score 2):

In fact all elements are there; just use an absolute path.

```
String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir"); // Alternative
Path cwdPath = Paths.get(cwd);
Path dbPath = Paths.get(cwd, "db/hogdb.fdb");
String db = dbPath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
if (!Files.exists(dbPath)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong path for database: " + db);
}
minDataBas = new InfDB(db);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead it should be

```
minDataBas = new InfDB("C:\\Hogwarts\\db\\HOGDB.FDB");
```